# JavaScript: Push to Array with unknown key names

Tags: javascript

I have a small program that returns JSON which I'm then interrogating before pushing it into an array.

An example of the data is as follows:

> id=1|owner=Vina San Pedro|brandName=1865 Chilean Wine|variantName=1865 Chilean Wine|quality=Standard|minorRegionName=Nordic Countries|vol02=0|vol07=0|vol08=4.25|vol09=4.25|vol10=0|

I can iterate the above string, pushing the values into the array, but how can I 'name' the key in the array based on the field name from JSON, considering that items such as "Vol02", "Vol07" may be marked as "val02", "val07", or "minorRegionName" can in some cases by "majorRegionName".

*edit*

```
  var finalSplit = brandDataRow.split('|');
                                $.each(finalSplit, function (x, y) {
                                    var v = y.split('=');
                                    $.each(v, function (m, n) {
                                        formattedBrandData.push({ m: m }, { n: n });
                                    });
                                });
```

In the above example, if my | delimiterred string contains "Owner=??????|Value=????????|Brand=???????" then when I push this into an array, I want the keys to be "Owner", "Value" and "Brand".

BUT, I don't know the key names until after I've returned the data, so sometimes the | delimitered string could be "Owner=??????|Line=???????|Region=??????"

Comment: The data looks exactly like your example? Thts not even nearly JSON formatted!

Comment: True, but I never said that was JSON data, I said I'm returning JSON data BEFORE interrogating - the data above is after the interrogation.

Comment: Can you show your code for "I can iterate the above string, pushing the values into the array"?

Comment: So you're taking well-formatted data (JSON) and turning it into a badly formatted string... then you want to parse that string to get it into an array? Do you see a flaw in this approach?

Comment: Not at all considering the JSON returned is absolutely perfect and suits a requirement, I'm then interrogating various elements of that JSON string, pushing it onto a | delimitered string which I then want to push into an array for further interrogation.

Comment: When you say "array" you mean "object", right? You want properties that are name/value pairs rather than numerically indexed values? Please show your desired (final) output. (Also, if you show your original JSON somebody might be able to suggest a method that skips the delimited string step.)

Comment: Yeah, "Object", sorry, still think of them as Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = "id=1|owner=Vina San Pedro|brandName=1865 Chilean Wine|variantName=1865 Chilean Wine|quality=Standard|minorRegionName=Nordic Countries|vol02=0|vol07=0|vol08=4.25|vol09=4.25|vol10=0|";

var keyVal = data.split("|");
var res = {};
for(var i =0; i< keyVal.length; i++) {
    var tmp = keyVal[i].split("=")
    res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
}
console.log(res);
```

Yes, it will return an object, but array can contain only numerical indexes. And in most cases you can work with object the same way as with array. Besides, see no reason to use $.each for such a simple task. Just an additional code to execute.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KSsFA/1/) - see console output

Comment: Yeah see what you mean about the $.each now you've shown that, exactly what I was after.  Thanks for showing me a better way of doing it.

Comment: see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KSsFA/2/) js fiddle - I've updated your code so it works correct. You just made a mistake when decided to iterate over the result of `.split("=")`. In your code you are getting only one piece of result at a time.

Answer (score 1):

First off: you're not looking for an array, but an object. JS Arrays are actually objects in drag, but that's not the point; JS doesn't have *associative arrays*, only objects. But to answer your question: IMO, the easiest (and, I suspect, quickest) way you can convert your string to an object is by converting it to valid JSON:

```
var str = 'id=1|owner=Vina San Pedro|brandName=1865 Chilean Wine|variantName=1865 Chilean Wine|quality=Standard|minorRegionName=Nordic Countries|vol02=0|vol07=0|vol08=4.25|vol09=4.25|vol10=0|';
var obj = JSON.parse('{"'+str.substring(0,str.length-1).replace(/(=|\|)/g,function(s1,s2)
{
    return '"'+(s2 === '=' ? ':' : ',')+'"';
})+'"}');
```

This is the dense version, if we break it down:

```
str.substring(0,str.length-1);//leave out trailing pipe (|)
//if the pipe is not always there:
str  = str.substr(-1) === '|' ? str.substring(0,str.length-1) : str;
```

Then replace all `=` and `|`:

```
str = str.replace(/(=|\|)/g,function(s1,s2)
{//s1 will be the entire matched substring, s2 the first group, not required in this case, but just so you know
    return '"'+(s2 === '=' ? ':' : ',') + '"';
});//pipes become comma's, = becomes colon
```

We're almost there now, the returned string will be `id":"1","owner":"Vina San Pedro","brandName":"1865 Chilean Wine","variantName":"1865 Chilean Wine","quality":"Standard","minorRegionName":"Nordic Countries","vol02":"0","vol07":"0","vol08":"4.25","vol09":"4.25","vol10":"0`. As you can see, all we need to add are the opening and closing curly's, and a double quote at the beginning and end of the string, and we end up with valid JSON:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"'+str+'"}');//returns object
//is the same as:
obj = { brandName: "1865 Chilean Wine",
        id: "1",
        minorRegionName: "Nordic Countries",
        owner: "Vina San Pedro",
        quality: "Standard",
        variantName: "1865 Chilean Wine",
        vol02: "0",
        vol07: "0",
        vol08: "4.25",
        vol09: "4.25",
        vol10: "0"};
```

From then on:

```
console.log(obj.id);//logs 1
console.log(obj.owner);//logs 'Vina San Pedro'
console.log(obj['brandName']);//string access: logs "1865 Chilean Wine"
//etc...
```

This code is tested and working

Comment: @JasonMHirst: Glad to help. I don't do this too often, but I would strongly suggest to use this approach? The approved answer constructs an object, splits a string (calling the `Array` constructor) and iterates that array, only to call the `Array` constructor on _every_ element again. It also uses a ton of additional variables (which increases the risk of accidental globals) _And_ it doesn't deal with the last `|` in the string, creating a nameless `undefined` property, too. I don't want to brag or boast, but I am convinced my solution is the better one

Answer (score 0):

You can use string to name the key.
Eg.

```
var sample = new Array();
sample["bob"] = 123;
sample.bob; //returns 123
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Don't do it! It's not creating an array with indexes. That does not exist in JavaScript. It will be converted to an object. Try `sample.length` to see what odds this brings with it.

Comment: @DanLee - It won't be _converted_ to an object: in JS an Array _is_ a type of object, and can have both numerically indexed properties and named properties. But you are correct that an Array is not the appropriate structure here, it should be a "plain" object as `var sample = {};`.